# Pass PayPal a PHP variable to send to after purchase page

Tags: php, html, paypal, web-hosting

I have recently been making a website for a hosting reseller.
I made a form that passes users variables to a page which creates user account.

```
<form id="form_14" action="https://1hosting1.co.uk/order/purchase.php" method="get" target="_self" class="OBJ-1" >
    <input id="user" name="user" class="OBJ-2" maxlength="32" placeholder="Username" >
    <input id="pwd" name="pwd" class="OBJ-2" maxlength="32" type="password" placeholder="Password" >
    <input id="submit" disabled="" class="OBJ-3" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <div class="OBJ-4" id="txt_9">
        <p class="Body3 P-2">
          <span class="C-4">Hosting Signup</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div id="txt_118">
        <h4 class="Heading-4 P-3">
          <span class="C-5">PASSWORD</span>
        </h4>
    </div>
     <input id="edit_6" name="email" class="OBJ-2" maxlength="32" placeholder="Email Address">
</form>
```

This passes the variables to a file that creates an account from the variables , using the GET method.
However what I want to do is when the user buys the product , it also sends paypal a list of variables that will then send it to the file.
Is there a way I can do this? 
---UPDATE----
Okay so I decided that PayPal would not suite my needs. Is there another payment gateway that can pass on PHP variables?

Comment: You're probably looking for the Callback API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/Callback_API_Operation_NVP/ or the Instant Update API https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/

Comment: @Fred-ii- I may be wrong , but this API seems to only send set variable names and values to the website.

Comment: maybe, but you can roam through their list of APIs to find exactly what you're looking to do. I thought one of those would have helped.

Comment: Ok Thanyou , Just as an alternative , is there any other payment gateways that fit to my description?

Comment: TBH Joel, I don't know apart from what I found.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `callback_url` like described in the [variables docu](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) of paypal. put your paramters in the url as get-parameters if you want to pass-through the variables.

alternatively save them in the session and check them out, if the callback comes back from paypal.